# how to upload few images use bitmapFactory?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How can I upload images one by one so that the memory is cleared each time after the picture upload has been successfully downloaded and the picture does not disappear from the screen?
Trying to load few images in RecyclerView. Important! Images are loaded from other applications (themes for my app).
Here is the code:

```
private static final int MAX_SAMPLE = 16;

private static Drawable getDrawableFromResource(Resources themeRes, int resourceID)
{
    if (resourceID == 0 || themeRes == null)
        return null;

    Drawable drawable = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options uniformOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    int inputSampleSize = uniformSampleSize;

    if (inputSampleSize > MAX_SAMPLE)
        inputSampleSize = MAX_SAMPLE;

    String resName = getResName(resourceID);

    for (int sizeDivider = inputSampleSize; sizeDivider <= MAX_SAMPLE; sizeDivider *= 2)
    {
        uniformOptions.inSampleSize = sizeDivider;
        try
        { bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(themeRes, resourceID, uniformOptions); }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError | Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(DynamicSettings.TAG_ERROR, "Load drawable: " + (resName != null ? resName : "name not found") + ", sizeDiv: " + sizeDivider);
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue; 
        }
        try
        {
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

            return drawable;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError | Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(DynamicSettings.TAG_ERROR, "Bad drawable resource file (parsing): " + resName);
            e.printStackTrace();   // Out of memory or Null pointer

            if (bitmap != null)
                bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }

    new BitmapDrawable(getErrorBitmap());
    return  new BitmapDrawable(getErrorBitmap());
}
```

If there is not enough memory for all the pictures – they resize using inSampleSize uniformOptions
Here's the error:

[image]

If you call bitmap.recycle() or something like that - image dissapear from RecyclerView and throw exception.

Comment: Unclear: `... the picture upload has been successfully downloaded ...` **up** OR **down**?

Comment: `If you call bitmap.recycle() or something like that - image dissapear from RecyclerView and throw exception.` ... which is, indeed, **the expected behavior** when you remove an object from the memory.

Comment: And `bitmap.recycle()` does exactly this.